# Не отображается рисунок в браузере

Tags: php, html, изображения, link

```
<img src="http://mbs/pics/700x100.jpg" width="700" height="100" alt="700x100"/>
```

На странице браузера вообще не показывается. Даже рамки на месте рисунка нет. http://itmages.ru/image/view/4207523/a74b205a

Если глянуть в исходный код и нажать на ссылку то рис открывается.
http://itmages.ru/image/view/4207522/0855e27d

ПОЧЕМУ ТАК???

Сам php файл состоит из нескольких частей. Они по `require` подключаются.

`x` — это маленькая английская буква `Х`. Если бы была опечатка, то при щелчке в исходном коде рис не открылся бы.

НО тот же файл с именем

```
<img src="http://mbs/pics/700_100.jpg" width="700" height="100" alt="700x100"/>
```

Показывается без проблем.

Формат рисунка:

```
700x100.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, comment: "Created with GIMP"
```

links:

[upload проверка загружаемых файлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603761/upload-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

[upload странное поведение браузеров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603174/upload-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2)

[Загружаемый файл находится во временной папке после окончания работы скрипта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538033/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0)

[Куда сервер деалет upload? (нет файла во временной папке). upload_tmp_dir](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537984/%d0%9a%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82-upload-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-upload-tmp-dir)

[минимальный размер файла для корректной работы exif_imagetype](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601796/ghj%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-exif-imagetype)

[Не отображается рисунок в браузере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518400/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно было открыть косоль разработчика и в разделе network поглядеть, с каким заголовоком приходит картинка, успешный ли ответ.

Дальше уже всё стало бы ясно, если ответ 200. а картинки нет - вариантов не много.

Comment: "если ответ 200. а картинки нет - вариантов не много." -  какие могут быть? Интересно знать?

Comment: картинка не показывалась потому что блокировщик рекламы ее заблокировал.