# Куда сервер деалет upload? (нет файла во временной папке). upload_tmp_dir

Tags: php, fileupload, upload

```
    <?php
    // В PHP 4.1.0 и более ранних версиях следует использовать $HTTP_POST_FILES
    // вместо $_FILES.

    $uploaddir = '/var/www/html/uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    echo '<pre>';
    /*
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "Файл корректен и был успешно загружен.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Возможная атака с помощью файловой загрузки!\n";
    }*/

    echo 'Некоторая отладочная информация:';
    print_r($_FILES);

    print "</pre>";

    ?>
```

[image: find не находит файл]

Где файл?

Переменная в php.ini

```
 upload_tmp_dir no value
```

Может после установки этой переменной файл реально будет во временной папке?
ИЛИ есть какой-то параметр php, который автоматически "делает уборку"?

---

НО если раскоментировать код (перемещение в папку ...uploads) код отработает без ошибок. Файл будет в ... uploads.

links:

[upload проверка загружаемых файлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603761/upload-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

[upload странное поведение браузеров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603174/upload-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2)

[Загружаемый файл находится во временной папке после окончания работы скрипта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538033/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0)

[Куда сервер деалет upload? (нет файла во временной папке). upload_tmp_dir](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537984/%d0%9a%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82-upload-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-upload-tmp-dir)

[минимальный размер файла для корректной работы exif_imagetype](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601796/ghj%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-exif-imagetype)

[Не отображается рисунок в браузере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518400/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php 
Если не использовать эту функцию, файлы будут находится во временной папке и удаляться после завершения работы PHP скрипта.

Comment: " и удаляться после завершения работы PHP скрипта." - то есть специально временную папку нен ужно чистить?

Comment: ГДЕ написано ??? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538033/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-upload-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8