# Загружаемый файл находится во временной папке после окончания работы скрипта?

Tags: php, документация

Этот вопрос получился из ответа на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537984/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82-upload-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-upload-tmp-dir).

Я ничего против php не имею, но в офф. документации не нашел такой информации.

Потому и спрашиваю "*Где в офф документации написано что upload файл живет во временной папке до окончания работы скрипта?*"

links:

[upload проверка загружаемых файлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603761/upload-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

[upload странное поведение браузеров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603174/upload-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2)

[Загружаемый файл находится во временной папке после окончания работы скрипта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538033/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0)

[Куда сервер деалет upload? (нет файла во временной папке). upload_tmp_dir](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537984/%d0%9a%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82-upload-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-upload-tmp-dir)

[минимальный размер файла для корректной работы exif_imagetype](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601796/ghj%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-exif-imagetype)

[Не отображается рисунок в браузере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518400/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Идем в доки http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Читаем строку ровно в конце пункта `Пример #2 Проверка загружаемых на сервер файлов`:

> По окончанию работы скрипта, в случае, если принятый файл не был
>   переименован или перемещен, он будет автоматически удален из временной
>   папки.

Happy End!

Comment: уже увидел! __.