# upload проверка загружаемых файлов

Tags: php, файлы, изображения, безопасность, upload

У меня идут такие проверки:

```
ПРОВЕРКА ISSET($_FILES['IMG'])

ПРОВЕРКА НА КОЛИЧЕСТВО ЗАГРУЖАЕМЫХ ФАЙЛОВ

ПРОВЕРКА ПО МАССИВУ ОШИБОК

ПРОВЕРКА ВЕСА (КБ, МБ)

ПРОВЕРКА ФОРМАТОВ

ПРОВЕРКА РАЗМЕРОВ КАРТИНКИ (РАЗМЕР СТОРОН КАРТИНКИ)
```

После этого я хочу сделать ресайз картигки,  и снова проверить ФОРМАТ файла. Нужна ли эта проверка?

Имена загружаемых не проверяю - не нужны. Типы проверять ($_FILES['type']) - нет никакого смысла.

Зачем ЕЩЕ раз, после ресайза, проверять формат картинки? А вдруг кто-то внедрит туда злой код?

ВСЯ графика (кроме того что используется для дизайна) на сайте сохраняется БЕЗ расширений, выше корня сайта. Повторюсь: Нужно ли еще раз проверять формат картинки, после ресайза?

links:

[upload проверка загружаемых файлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603761/upload-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

[upload странное поведение браузеров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603174/upload-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2)

[Загружаемый файл находится во временной папке после окончания работы скрипта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538033/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0)

[Куда сервер деалет upload? (нет файла во временной папке). upload_tmp_dir](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537984/%d0%9a%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82-upload-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-upload-tmp-dir)

[минимальный размер файла для корректной работы exif_imagetype](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601796/ghj%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-exif-imagetype)

[Не отображается рисунок в браузере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/518400/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5)

Comment: Одного ресайза вообще достаточно. Если он прошел, то это картинка и все ок, если нет, то загрузили что-то другое.

Comment: не вполне согласен. Если файл не картинка, то сразу же будет выход  и сообщение об ошибке. а если делать только ресайз(без указанных проверок), то если файл не картинка, то, НАВЕРНОЕ, будет затрачено чуть больше ресурсов на ресайз не картинки (ИЛИ перед попыткой ресайза функция imagecopyresampled проверяет файл на соответствие граф формату, если ошибка,  то не расайзит)? Количество файлов, вес и резмер картинки тоже нужно проверять - так что ТОЛЛЬКО РЕСАЙЗ в данном случае не уместен.

Comment: В ресайзе первая функция, которая вызывается это getimagesize(), которая даст первичный ответ картинка это или нет, формат картинки, размер. Или вы ресайз одной функцией imagecopyresampled() делаете? :)

Comment: та не одной. Мне также нужно проверять минимальные размеры картинки. Ну вообзем у меня, кажись, остался один вопрос относительно аплоада. И после его решения, наверное, всё.(?) Сейчас нужно проверить кое-что. Потом придется разместить крослинки на  мои вопросы.

Comment: Вопросов уже нет!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если метод ресайза картинки находится в том же классе и является private методом, тоесть нет никакой возможности избежать первых проверок, то дополнительная проверка бессмыслена.
Если в метод ресайза можно попасть из других мест, то все проверки лучше оформить в отдельном приватном методе и вызывать этот метод везде, где идет работа с картинками.

Comment: У меня функц ресайза отдельная и функц созранение тож отдельная. А указанные выше проверки все в одной функции. Я нахожусь за полшага к пониманию ООП, но я специаольно не хочу вникать. Потому что если начну детально вникать в ООП, то никогда не смогу ДОписать сайт.  Вопрос, кажись, решен.